# Facebook Page Advertising Issue

Tags: facebook, advertising, social-media

I am gonna take this from one of my answers, because it is still bugging me...

> Facebook Pages is a different story. They make you pay for the views of getting your post out to people who have already liked the page. Then, to get your page out to new people, they make you pay for advertising the page to new people. So, I wouldnt recommend this method for pages.
>
> Groups on facebook do work, pages are a money waste, but if you do have a popular page with 2000 likes or more, the stats I got from that was on average for 5 USD in one day only for boosting a post: 30 Likes, 8 Comments, and 10,000 views of that post.

Should I actually pay for my post when it first comes out? I do only post on the page once a week. So 5 USD for one day right after the post justifies the cost to get to people which I already got to like the page? Or should I just go with advertising on the groups which I am a member of?

Comment: Downvoted for lack of info. What benefit do you get, on average, per post view? What is your average cost per acquisition? Without knowing further details about your particular cost-benefit situation, it's tough to give you an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It kind of depends on what you want the post to do: inform or attract.

When you join a group, it's presumably because you agree with the aims or principles of the group or you are a member of the class that the group targets. This usually means that the other group members are broadly similar to you in interests and tastes and thus Groups are the better bet for attracting new people to your page. If you like what they like, the odds are they will like what you are offering on your page and your engagement rate will be higher.

However, as the quoted answer above indicate, promoting page posts is something akin to a scam in that all you are doing in most cases is making the post show up in the timeline longer/higher/more often/whatever.  While this will have some positive effect on people who already like your page, it doesn't do quite as much to attract new people.  Furthermore, going after friends of people who have liked your page is much less effective in terms of attracting new followers. What appeals to someone who is similar to you may not appeal to their circle of  friends, their spouse, or their relatives.  You will get some level of likes and maybe even a re-share but the odds on a friend of a friend being sufficiently interested in your page are significantly less as it's an indirect relationship.

Targeting the audience provides you with some ability to control who sees the post and you would think that would be highly effective in getting more likes but the [reality is somewhat different](https://www.jonloomer.com/2014/02/11/facebook-fraud-response/) and if you search around a bit for statistics on clickthrough rates after controlling for the targeted demographic the results are fairly bleak.

On the other hand, if the post is meant to inform your page followers of something specific, promoting it will have that effect and it may be worth the cost. Promoting a post to followers will get it in front of just those people and raise awareness of the post content to your existing targets.  It doesn't necessarily help you grow a follower count but if you need people to take action, it can be a pretty effective tool.

Comment: It just seems like a total waste of time time re-reach the community that I love have already established.

Comment: It is kind of a waste but I'm trying to answer your question as asked ("where should I spend the money?") instead of answering a different question ("should I spend the money?"). If you want an argument for not promoting at all: I don't think there is a great use case for promoting posts with dollars.  It's a short-term, short-sighted solution that makes people feel good ("look at all the people I reached!") instead of providing true engagement.